# C++ invalid initialization of reference of type 'const std ::?

Tags: c++, r

I'm trying to developp some c++ functions in order to reuse them within my R project.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

double scalar_product(std::vector<double> const& a, std::vector<double> const& b)
{
  if (a.size() != b.size()) { throw std::runtime_error("different sizes"); }

  return std::inner_product(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), 0.0);
} // scalar_product


double hashC(double x, double y) {


double  ys = scalar_product(x , y);

    if (ys > 0) {
      return 1;
    } else if (ys == 0) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }


}

/*** R
x=c(1,2,3,4)
  y=c(-1,-2,-3,-5)
  d=hashC(x,y)
  print("d")
  print(d)
  */
```

I got an error : `invalid initialization of reference of type 'const std :: ......`

The error is shown within that line :

```
 double  ys = scalar_product(x , y);
```

Sorry but i'm not good at c++.

Comment: Please don't cut of error messages. You left out all the important information that tells you what the problem is! Please add the full error message to your question.

Comment: Why are you passing `double`'s to a function that expects vectors of doubles?  Voting to close as a typo for passing the wrong data types.

Comment: scalar_product is accepting params of type vector but you are passing variables of type double. May be thats a problem!

Comment: @ NathanOliver The first function returns a scalar product of 2 vectors with type = double

Comment: @mouad2020 `scalar_product` takes two `std::vector<double> const&`'s.  In `hashC`, `x` and `y` are `double`, not `std::vector<double>`.

Comment: I think i resolved the problem based on your comments , thank you a lot !

Comment: I still have a problem ; i can't use the function hashC within R :  in r console , i tried sourceCpp("C:/Users/mouad/Videos/Private/mouad.cpp")

Comment: Sounds like you should be using `Rcpp::NumericVector`'s instead of `std::vector`'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments of `scalar_product` are both of type `std::vector<double> const&`, you are passing `double` type variables, the variables passed as argument must be of compatible type.

Comment: I still have a problem ; i can't use the function hashC within R : in r console ,                 i tried  :   sourceCpp("C:/Users/mouad/Videos/Private/mouad.cpp")

Comment: @mouad2020 this is an interesting question, I would argue you should ask another question reporting this problem with details.

Comment: Ok @anastaciu . I will wait some days because there are persons who gives me bad votes for my question . Thank you for your valuable help !

Comment: @mouad2020 The DV's are usually related to the lack of compliance with the asking standards of the site, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), these are quick reads and can help you have better chances of getting UV's.

Comment: i found the solution of the second probelm .  I should use this prefixe // [[Rcpp::export]] in c++ before each c++ function that i want it to be available within R.

Comment: ; i will read the asking standards of the site.  Thank you again !